# Changing url link for page in processwire

Tags: processwire

I'm looking for a way to change the redirect for a page in processwire.
Logging in the admin back end I see this order page 
[image]

Upon editing:
[image]

But the redirect url from header meta I guess still redirects to the previous link. I tried looking in the database and changed it there also but it still keeps it in settings somewhere.
Any ideas where this is?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you expect the page to redirect via a meta description tag. Meta description is for SEO, to tell search engines what the page is about. If your page has a meta redirect tag - which should look like

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`

it doesn't seem to be edititable via your CMS. Either change it directly in the templates, or add a field for this to the backend and add an output in the template.